# Why cannot we just use [][] instead of int[][]?

Tags: c#, arrays

### Case 1:

```
int[] data1 = new int [] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

can be simplified as

```
int[] data2 = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

### Case 2:

```
int[][] table1 = new int[][] { new int[] { },  new int[] { 1, 2 } };
```

cannot be simplified as

```
int[][] table2 = new [][] { new int[] { }, new int[] { 1, 2 } };
```

### Question:

For the second case, why cannot we just use `[][]` instead of `int[][]`?

Comment: The correct syntax is `int[][] table2 = new [] { new int[] { }, new int[] { 1, 2 } };` and the compiler will infer `int[]` as the array elements type. Note that `var table2 = new [] { new int[] { }, new [] { 1, 2 } };` works just as well.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: _"Why"_ questions are always difficult, only a few people know for sure. But likely: because the use of multidimensional/jagged arrays is rare, initialization even rarer. Just not worth adding language features for.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery +1 for alternate syntax but the OP wants to be able to leave off all type names in the initializer.  So, an actual answer to this question (if at all possible, see Henk's remark) would need to either provide syntax which doesn't use `int` in the initializer or provide a (documented) reason why it can't be done.

Comment: @Chris I'm hesitant, my comment doesn't exactly explain "why" it cannot be done. Probably only the language designers could.

Comment: @yuck: You don't need the int for the second internal array but you do need it for the first one becuase without any elements it can't infer what the type is otherwise.

Comment: @Chris Right, that's more of an answer to the question. Perhaps you should post it? ;)

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: I assume its because when it implicitly determines arrays it considers just arrays and if you want an array of arrays you just let it type the contents of the array as arrays. That is `int[][]` is an array of array of ints so when doing it implicitly you say you have an array and then let it work out that it's type is array of int. There would be no point programing in support for `new [][]` as a separate thing...

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery : Thanks for your comment. It should be posted as an answer. One thing I am still confused with is the fact `new int[n]` represents an array of elements of type `int` but `new int[][n]` must be written as `new int[n][]` to represent an array of elements of type `int[]`. The pattern seems to be inconsistent. What do you think?

Comment: It is consistent, you always specify the highest dimensions first. `int[n]` then `int[n][]` then `int[n][m][]`...

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: For the cases where compiler can infer, `new int[]` may be simplified as `new []`, `new int[][]` may be simplified as `new []`, `new int[][][]` may be simplified as `new []`. I can conclude that `new <type> []` represents an array of type `<type>`. Now consider `new int[n]`, `new int[n][]`, `new int[n][][]`, `new int[n][][][]` which become better if we can write them as `new int[n]` (the same), `new int[][n]`, `new int[][][n]` and `new int[][][][n]` because we can conclude `new <type>[n]` represent an array of `n` elements of type `<type>`.

Comment: Anything between `new` and the last `[]` represents the type of elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `int[][]` is an array of arrays. If you are explicitly typing it as `int[][]` then it works (as you can see) but if you are using implicit typing then the code works it out differently.

the syntax `new []` says "I'm creating an array but I want you to work out the type. Consider the following working example:

```
new [] { new int [] { }, new [] { 1, 42 } }
```

Here we say we want a new implicitly typed array. The compiler then looks at our initialiser to work out the type of that array. In this case it sees two items: the first is an explicitly typed empty array of type `int[]`, the second is an implicitly typed array. When the compiler examines the second item's contents it discovers it is an `int[]` as well so determines that the overall expression defines an `int[][]`.

In the above example we need to explicitly type the first empty array because otherwise the compiler would have no idea of its type since it has no items to use to determine the type.

Thanks to William Andrew Montgomery for providing me the first hint to get to this answer.

Comment: You snooze, you lose. ;-)